# Cookies or Rootscope in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I use cookies.putObject generally to send data to another controller.But i see some people use rootscope.broadcast.What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cookie` data will be stored in user system as a file and allows limited data to be stored. This is not a good approach to share data between controllers.

**If you just want to share the data between controllers, you should used `service` or `factory`.**

Where as `$rootScope.$broadcast` is sending an event through the application scope. When you raise the event you can send data along with it. Any controller which have subscribed the event can get the data.

To know more about `$broadcast`, check this [link](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/)